# Package expss - function f not found

Tags: r, expss

Function f described on page 20 of reference manual "Package expss" on Cran.

```
data(mtcars)
var_lab(mtcars$am) = "Transmission"
val_lab(mtcars$am) = c(automatic = 0, manual=1)
## Not run:
plot(f(mtcars$am))
## End(Not run)
table(f(mtcars$am))
summary(lm(mpg ~ am, data = mtcars)) # no labels
summary(lm(mpg ~ f(am), data = mtcars)) # with labels
summary(lm(mpg ~ f(unvr(am)), data = mtcars)) # without variable label
```

When I run this I get the following error. Package expss is loaded {library(expss)
Error in f(mtcars$am) : could not find function "f"

What am I missing here?

Comment: Actually, it's `fctr` as in `summary(lm(mpg ~ fctr(am), data = mtcars)) # with labels`. This is in page `help('fctr')`.